# Scania 4 series P140c 4th gear hard shift

Tags: manual-transmission, shifting, scania

I have purchased an ex Australian Military Scania 4-series, 2002, P140c, 4x4, with manual 3x3 gearbox.
Although its over 20years old, it has only 50k kms on the truck. amazing condition. Ex military should mean it was well serviced and looks that way. Love the truck. Changing into 4th gear is an issue:( Must be at right speed and revs or she grinds like mongrel until you get the revs and speed just right.

Its behaving like the syncro in non-existent on 4th gear:( Gear box oil has been changed and is now Penrite 80w140 fully synth "Pro Gear". Old oil looked fine (not burnt etc).
Any thoughts other than strip gearbox and replace synchro? Yes I am changing very very slowly:)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

As I recommended in another one of your posts, try adding [Archoil 9100](https://www.u-buy.com.au/brand/archoil) to the gear oil at a [treat rate](https://www.archoil.com/blogs/tech/how-to-treat-your-engine-with-archoil-ar9100-friction-modifier) of 3.2 oz. per quart.  In addition to its anti-friction and metal conditioning properties, it has extra detergent which will deep clean.  If you notice improvement, replace the oil & additive again in a few thousand kms.